# Ruby system call with environment variables in windows

Tags: ruby, windows, powershell, environment-variables

I need to set some environment variables before I execute a command on a windows machine calling it inside a ruby script. 
On Linux, you can do

```
cmd = 'echo $FOO'
system({'FOO' => '123'}, cmd) 

OUTPUT is "123"
```

But on windows this does not work, the output is $FOO

How can I set an environment variable on windows ruby system calls. I several variations of ENV and got errors or still does not work.

```
system({$ENV[:VAR1] => "WIN7"}, 'echo $ENV[:VAR1]')
```

Comment: What is the command you're trying to issue to your shell?

Comment: I'm trying to access the environment variables, as stated in the example I have windows uses $ENV[:var], but accessing this environment variable doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby's `system()` invokes whatever the host's default shell is, so *you need to speak that shell's language*.

The default shell on Windows is `cmd.exe`, where environment variable `FOO` must be referenced as `%FOO%` in order to be expanded.

Thus, your code should be:

```
cmd = 'echo %FOO%'
system({'FOO' => '123'}, cmd)
```

Comment: Hi mkelement, with ordinary variables, yes it does work fine, but what I was trying to do was use the environment variables (ENV). Does that make sense? Sorry if I wasn't very clear.

Comment: @ibaralf: In `cmd.exe`, _all_ variables are _environment_ variables, so `%FOO%` does indeed reference environment variable `FOO`.